# Why let a = [{}] and a.indexOf({}) -1?

Tags: javascript

IndexOf cannot find my object. Here is the [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8qpm90Ld/1/)

[image]

```js
let a = [{}]
console.log(a.indexOf({}))
```

Comment: Because `{} !== {}`. Try `a.indexOf(a[0])`.

Comment: Every distinct object is `!==` to every other object.

Comment: When you compare objects it checks whether the two operands refer to the same object in memory. `indexOf` obviously use equality internally. `{} === {}` is `false`